# jQuery if one of three checkboxs is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have these 3 checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ProjectID[]" value="5896" style="float: left; width: 1.5%;">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ProjectID[]" value="5898" style="float: left; width: 1.5%;">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ProjectID[]" value="5897" style="float: left; width: 1.5%;">3<br>
```

and I am trying to use jquery to validate that at least 1 was selected.

I have been trying just to return true or false in a console log to make sure I am getting the correct value (true or false)

```
console.log($("input[type='checkbox'][name='ProjectID[]']").checked);
```

but this returns undefined.

Comment: jQuery collections don't have a checked property.

Comment: @KevinB my bad.

Comment: [Check this, `:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Following line of code gives you true if at least one checkbox is checked otherwise false.

```
 console.log($("input[name='ProjectID[]']:checked").length> 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
console.log($("input[type='checkbox'][name='ProjectID[]'][checked]").length > 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="ProjectID[]" checked value="5896" style="float: left; width: 1.5%;">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ProjectID[]" value="5898" style="float: left; width: 1.5%;">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ProjectID[]" value="5897" style="float: left; width: 1.5%;">3<br>
```